# What is the size of tab bar icon that works for Android and Ios in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, icons

I want to create custom icons in my tabbar (which created by [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux)). Is there any restriction on the tab bar icon size in Ios and Android?

In Ios, the recommended size is 30 x 30 while in Android the suggestion is 24 x 24.

I don't want to create the icons respectively, so I wonder is there icon size that works on both platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different sizes work as well but like you said they wouldn't follow the platform's specific guidelines. I would define the icon size like this:

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

const dimensions = {
  iconSize: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 30 : 24,
}
```